# Не работает вывод в самописном менеджере контекста

Tags: python

```
import time 

class TimeManager: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.startTime = time.time()
        self.timeExec = 0
    
    def __enter__(self): 
        self.timeEnd = time.time()
        self.timeExec = self.timeEnd - self.startTime
        return self.timeExec
    
    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_val, trace):
        return True
    
    def printTime(self): 
        print(self.timeExec)

def foo():
    a = 1
    for i in range(10000):
        a += i 
    print(a)
    return a


with TimeManager() as tm: 
    # foo()
    print('freg')
    tm.printTime()
```

При выводе на принт хотелось бы, чтобы выводил разницу во времени или хотя бы что-нибудь. Но вывод как будто вообще не работает. Консоль просто пустая. При этом обычный принт срабатывает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замечания:

- Из `__enter__` лучше возвращать `self`
- Разницу лучше считать в `__exit__` и там можно выводить
- Намудрили с определением разницы по времени - ее нужно брать в конце и от того же метода, от которого берете начальное время, т.е. `time.time()`
- Имена переменных и методов рекомендуется в змеиной нотации писать

Обратите внимание, что `__exit__` вызывается после выхода из контекстного менеджера, а значит вывод `tm.print_time()` будет раньше, чем аналогичный в `__exit__` и разница по времени на этот момент еще не будет известна

Пример:

```
import time


class TimeManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = 0
        self.time_exec = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.time_exec = time.time() - self.start_time
        self.print_time()

    def print_time(self):
        print(f'Total time: {self.time_exec:.3f} sec')


def foo():
    a = 1
    for i in range(10000):
        a += i
    print(a)
    return a


with TimeManager() as tm:
    # foo()
    print('freg')
    tm.print_time()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Некоторые моменты упростил (как return True) для того, чтобы понять ошибку, но оказалось, что наоборот усложнил. Спасибо за пояснение.
Змеиная нотация рекомендуется по PEP? Или в какой-то другой литературе?

Comment: @DarkSpace, пожалуйста :) Да, pep8

Answer (score 4):

Чтоб получить менеджер через as нужно вернуть self, а не значение.

```
def __enter__(self):
    .....
    return self
```

Вы бы увидели ошибку если б не заглушили все ошибки в

```
def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_val, trace):
    return True  # глушит ошибки
```